# Printing the contents of the  upper / second half of an array

Tags: java

I want to print the contents of the second half of an array, or copy it to another new array.

I have this method:

```
public static void evaluateF3(int[] anArray) {

int[] array2 = new int[anArray.length/2];
    for( int i = 0; i<array2.length; i++) {
        for(int j= (anArray)/2; j<anArray.length;j++) {
            array2[i]= anArray[j];
            System.out.print(" "+ array2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However it prints the same number of times as the inside for loop, when I only want to print once. I've tried taking the statement outside of the for loop, but then it just says it cannot find 'i'. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: you want to print the contents of the second half of the array, is that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking to do something [like this](http://ideone.com/yY5Qj)?

```
public static void evaluateF3(int[] anArray) {
  int[] array2 = new int[anArray.length/2]; 
  for(int i = 0, j= array2.length; j<anArray.length;i++, j++) {
    array2[i]= anArray[j];
    System.out.print(" "+ array2[i]);
  }
}

int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
evaluateF3(a); // 5 6 7 8
int[] a = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2 };
evaluateF3(a); // 0 0 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put it outside the inner loop, but still inside the outer loop, then it should print out properly.

Btw: you got a compile error in your second loop. Either you meant to say `j= anArray.length;` or `j = anArray.length/2`. In either case you forgot the `.length`

I figured out your problem you dont need the second loop

```
public static void evaluateF3(int[] anArray) {
    int[] array2 = new int[anArray.length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        array2[i] = anArray[i + (array2.length)];
        System.out.print(" " + array2[i]);
    }
}
```

Let me know!

Comment: Yes I tried that but it doesn't print as it should for example with the input:

 int[] array = new int[8];
 array[0]= 0;
 array[1]=1;
 array[2]=1;
 array[3]=0;
 array[4]=0;
 array[5]=0;
 array[6]=2;
    array[7]=2;

it would print 2222 not 0022

Comment: I'm copying the last half of the array into a new array and printing out the contents of the new array. So if the initial array is denoted by 'array' as given above the new array should have the contents 0,0,2,2 as these are the elements in the last half of the array

Comment: Yes it's this one j = anArray.length/2

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide an array int[] over 2: `(anArray)/2`

Answer (score 1):

*I think*<sup>(1)</sup> you want to copy the *upper half* of elements into a new array. Then you just need one for loop (if you want to do it with loops):

```
public static void evaluateF3(int[] anArray) {
  // assuming that anArray.size() is even!!

  int[] array2 = new int[anArray.length/2]; 
  for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    array2[i]= anArray[i + anArray.length/2];
    System.out.print(" "+ array2[i]);
  }
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Just read your comment to another answer, I think I got it right*

Comment: Just a note that the question doesn't define waht will happen if the array has an even number of elements... @Labra should specify it :)

Comment: @woliveirajr - *even* size is OK, *odd* size is undefined. That's why I added a small comment in my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an example of the code you're looking for is as follows:

```
public static void evaluateF3(int[] array1) {
    int[] array2 = new int[array1.length / 2];

    System.arraycopy(array1, array1.length / 2, array2, 0, array2.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int i = 0; i<array2.length; i++) 
{
  for(int j= (anArray.length)/2; j<anArray.length;j++)
  {
    array2[i]= anArray[j];
  }
   System.out.print(" "+ array2[i]);
}
```

That would print the value of each index in the array2.  Do you want it to print once after both of the loops?

Comment: Just FYI (just noticed) the second for-loop doesn't compile see my answer for moth detail